# sqlite automatically converts string to integer when inserting incorrect types

Tags: string, sqlite, integer

I am doing some basic sqlite. I have a relation named A. 2 tuples named C,D. The tuples accept integer values. But when I try to insert string values, sqlite still accepts them

for exp:

insert into A values ('1','2');

the above sql statement executes successfully. So does sqlite automatically convert the values of type 'string' into integer values? In other words, sqlite doesn't perform a check on tuples' constraints

Comment: Not only on sqlite, other databases also accept integer values in quotes ('). Internally it will convert to integer and save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); it will accept values of any type.

If you really want the database to check the type, add a CHECK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    C INTEGER CHECK(typeof(C) = 'integer'),
    D INTEGER CHECK(typeof(D) = 'integer')
);
```