# Does sqlite automatically convert a given input to the declared type

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I realized there's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128944/sqlite-automatically-converts-string-to-integer-when-inserting-incorrect-types) on SO, but it didn't fully explain my situation.

According to sqlite doc, specifically [SQLite's FAQ](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q3):

> But SQLite does use the declared type of a column as a hint that you
>   prefer values in that format. So, for example, if a column is of type
>   INTEGER and you try to insert a string into that column, SQLite will
>   **attempt to convert the string into an integer**. If it can, it inserts
>   the integer instead. If not, it inserts the string. This feature is
>   called type affinity

Based on this I was hoping any (possible) conversions will be taking care of by sqlite, with that in mind I've implemented the following code

```
# partial implementaion
def create_database(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderBook(
                Action TEXT, OrderID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Timestamp INTEGER, Symbol TEXT,
                OrderType TEXT, Side TEXT, Price REAL, Quantity INTEGER
                CHECK(TYPEOF(Quantity) == 'integer'))"""
    cur.execute(table)

def processQueries(conn, queries):
    query_list = queries.split(",")
    action = query_list[0]
    # query_list = query_list[:-1] + [int(query_list[-1])]


    if action == "N":
        print("test: ", action)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        sql = """ INSERT INTO OrderBook VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) """
        cur.execute(sql, query_list)
        # validation (duplicate id, invalid input field)
        conn.commit()

a = "N,3,0000002,XYZ,L,B,104.53,100"
processQueries(conn, a)
```

Got error

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: OrderBook
```

If I manually make the conversion to `int` for `Quantity`, then everything moves smoothly.

When will sqlite attempt data type conversion?

Comment: Based on documentation and SO question that you linked, SQLite will attempt to cast it to desired type, but when you use CHECK you enforce type and no casting is performed.

Comment: Did you mean CHECK suppress the casting as an error is raised before it's able to reach the conversion step?

Comment: Yes, by using CHECK you explicitly disable implicit cast. At least that is said in docs and examples.

Comment: If not using `CHECK`, would there be any alternatives to tell if the casting has successfully done? In other words, how to enforce a data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type is indeed checked before the conversion (the latter happens implicitly in line 9 while inserting):

```sql
> CREATE TABLE t(x INTEGER CHECK (typeof(x) = 'integer'));
> EXPLAIN INSERT INTO t VALUES('42');
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     11    0                    00  Start at 11
1     OpenWrite      0     2     0     1              00  root=2 iDb=0; t
2     NewRowid       0     1     0                    00  r[1]=rowid
3     String8        0     2     0     42             00  r[2]='42'
4     Copy           2     4     0                    00  r[4]=r[2]
5     PureFunc0      0     4     3     typeof(1)      01
6     Eq             5     8     3                    51  if r[3]==r[5] goto 8
7     Halt           275   2     0     t              03
8     MakeRecord     2     1     3     D              00  r[3]=mkrec(r[2])
9     Insert         0     3     1     t              39  intkey=r[1] data=r[3]
10    Halt           0     0     0                    00
11    Transaction    0     1     1     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
12    String8        0     5     0     integer        00  r[5]='integer'
13    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

Type affinity exists only for compatibility with other databases. If you know your columns, you should use the correct type to begin with.